# Which way to write this code is most the efficient?

Tags: php, html

If I am inside a ton of PHP code, instead of coming out of PHP I usually write code which contains variables like so:

```
echo "This is how I use a ".$variable." inside a string";
```

but is it more efficient to actually get out of PHP like so:

```
?>

Should I instead use the <? echo $variable; ?> like this

<? // then back into PHP
```

Throughout a page there will be lots of instances of code like this as I fill pages with dynamic content, or is this too much of a generalisation?

Comment: You'll never notice a difference in performance between the two, it's so small as to be practically immeasurable.... if you need to optimize, profile your scripts, and look at SQL queries and file access.... they're much bigger overheads

Comment: the performance of `echo` variables one or the other way are barely the same.

Comment: If I need to write only one line of code I use echo, but when it's several html lines I get out of php. But it would be interesting to know if there is a performance difference between the two.

Comment: Ideally you wouldn't mix lots of PHP with your HTML (except in templates). You'd separate your display logic with some form of templating.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I only suggest breaking out of php tags when echoing HTML, not just a string.

This is fine for just a string:

```
// You don't need to concat, double quotes interpolate variables
echo "This is how I use a $variable inside a string";
```

But with HTML, personally, I like to do this:

```
<?php //... ?>
<div>
    <span>This is how I use a <?=$variable?> inside HTML</span>
</div>
<?php //... ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using echo appears to be slightly faster.  I made this simple benchmark script:

```
<?php
$variable = "hello world";
$num = 10000;
$start1 = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i<$num;$i++) {    
    echo "test " . $variable . " test\n";    
}
$time1 = microtime(true) - $start1;
$start2 = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i<$num;$i++) {
    ?>test <?php echo $variable;?> test
<?
}
$time2 = microtime(true) - $start2;
echo "\n$time1\n$time2\n";
```

The `echo` loop was consistently about 25% faster.

In reality this difference is so minor it wouldn't have any impact on overall performance unless you were literally doing millions of such output statements.  I would still recommend using `echo` just because it's more straightforward and easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

`echo 'This is how I use a'.$variable.' inside a string';` is probably the most efficient here..

In your first case, you're using `"`, which causes the entire string to be evaluated for inline variables.

In your second case, I'd imagine that the context switch can be a little more expensive for the interpreter than in my sample.

Having said that, you're looking at a negligible difference either way.

Comment: Not necessarily the most efficient, as you're concatenating... just passing a series of unconcatenated arguments to echo separated by commas will be ever-so-fractionally more efficient

Comment: @MarkBaker: Yes, it's more efficient with a number of arguments, but more efficient to concatenate with a single variable. Where the trade-off lies exactly I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Yes just use `<?php ..... ?>` between your non-PHP (HTML) wherever you need. You can even have a do-while , for loops inside them.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use printf() as follows:

```
// your variable
$my_variable = "Stack Overflow";

printf("Real programmers graduate on %s", $my_variable);

// this prints 'Real programmers graduate on Stack Overflow,
```

Plus has the added bonus of not needing to concatenate frequently.
However it might be worth finding out how it performs as compared to echo statement

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, it is recommended to not use the short tags for php. In any case, if you're inside double quotes, you don't even have to use the concat dots to output a variable. You can just do this:

```
echo "This is how I use a $variable inside a string";
```

or this:

```
echo "This is how I use a {$variable} inside a string";
```

The second example allows expressions (array elements and object properties) to be delimited by the curly braces. You can use them in the first example too but the greediness of the variable parsing sometimes causes problems. Using the curly braces stops that.